# Why are the elementary functions the ones that they are?

Tags: integration, functions, elementary-functions

Many antiderivatives exist but cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. This got me thinking, well, what if we expanded the set of elementary functions? Would it work then?

Let's think of some elementary functions, such as addition. Addition is used to define multiplication (at leas tin the reals). A product is just addition a certain number of times. Exponentiation is just multiplication a certain number of times. This implies an infinite sequence let $f(x, y, n)$ be the "super exponential" where $x, y$ are reals and $f(x, y, n) = f(x, f(x, f(x, ..., n-1) , n-1), n-1)$ i.e. you apply the f of the lower level $y$ times to $x$.

Simply put $f(x,y,0) = x + y$ (addition), $f(x,y,1) = f(x,f(x, ... ,0), 0) = x + x + x...$ (multiplication). I am too lazy to do exponentiation, but you can see how that recursive definition can also give you exponentiation by recursively applying multiplication $y$ times, which itself applies addition $x$ times for every nesting. Thus this pattern can continue on and on to infinity. However we only consider elementary functions to be those up to $n=2$ (exponentiation) as far as I know.

Trig has a similar thing, cos and sin are the 2D coordinates of a point on the unit circle. Well I can define transine as the z coordinate in a 3D sphere and come up with a generalized version of sine and cosine that works there. And I can do this for any arbitrary hypersphere, once again getting infinitely many such functions with their own properties.

The question isn't whether any of these 2 is actually a solution to finding closed forms of antiderivatives but rather. What's so special about the functions we picked as elementary functions? Do they actually capture something so essential that just adding more complexity by increasing dimensions of recursion won't really add anything or bring something new to the table?

Comment: The idea that multiplication is defined in terms of repeated addition is not true for reals, only for natural numbers. While the definition for real numbers uses the definition for rationals, and the definition for rationals in terms of naturals, that puts the use of repeated addition deeply hidden for reals.

Comment: Some functions, such as polynomials, are at the bedrock of math in part because they are composed of the elementary (and pre-math) concepts of addition and multiplication.  "Simple" functions get added to our set by the classes of problems they solve and the mathematical simplicity of basic operations.  The fact that harmonic problems are ubiquitous, it is natural that $\sin$, $\cos$ and their variants are considered simple.  If we spent all our effort solving problems with exponentials (say), then functions like the Lambert W function would be recognized and used and considered "elementary."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Your answer seems to focus on the sparsity of problems that need these kinds of functions. But that is more a pragmatic consideration than a mathematical fact. Most people don't really use trig functions for example.

That doesn't mean that there's anything mathematically special about these functions in particular, the way say, $Ce^x$ is the only set of functions that are their own derivatives.

Comment: The same is true for exponentiation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Fair about that, but I assume you can still properly define a super exponential function and all other levels for the reals in a way that is consistent with a definition for the naturals.

Like $e^x^x^x^x^{...}$ a finite number of times is a computable function. One I don't want to compute, but it is computable.

Comment: The real key to “elementary functions” is that they can be implemented in terms of $e^x,\ln x,$ and $x,$ constant functions, along with addition, multiplication and composition of functions, as long as you consider the functions in terms of complex functions defined on some open subset of the complex numbers. We can add more functions, but there’s deep reasons that $e^x,\ln x$ are considered “simple.”

Comment: @Makogan:  "Most people don't really use trig functions..."  *Really*?  Trigonometry is taught in sixth grade, is the foundation for surveying, constructions, and innumerable other fields.  And then there is electronics, physics, astronomy, and an extraordinary number of problems where sines and cosines are essential.  Oh yes... and math.  And they solve one of the most fundamental differential equations one can imagine:  $f(x) \propto f^{\prime\prime}(x)$.  So yes, pragmatism is *certainly* a consideration of what we consider "elementary"... a good thing, too!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, I seem to have struck a chord there. Yes most people don't use trig. Most people do not use trig. Most people doesn't mean most fields. But just statistically, most people are not in STEM, most people don't even have a university degree. I am not sure why this struck a chord but what I said is statistically sound.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you, that is an insightful answer.

Comment: @Makogan:  Statistically sound... but irrelevant.  Clearly we're discussing the domain of people *who know what an "elementary function" is and care about them*, where "elementary function" includes (by your own words) functions like *exponentiation*.  Of course.  And here I would say the vast majority of such people do in fact know about them.  The fact that a shepherd in Ghana and billions like him never use $\sin$, $\cos$, etc., is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. The point is rather, that pragmatic use of mathematics is contextual. Shifts in economic factors, or technology, will affect the popularity of math. So, just because the majority of people do not use math, it doesn't mean elementary operations aren;t ubiquitous and important in STEM fields.

In a similar fashion, it's not because current STEM disciplines do not make use of other functions as much that those functions are intrinsically more descriptive of math than other functions. Which is what makes me wonder, we have proved that antiderivatives of some functions cannot be...

Comment: expressed in terms of elementary functions. Well, is there a set of functions out there that are computable but not expressable in terms of elementary functions that could provide analytic solutions to certain antiderivative problems?